# AVFoundation, limiting video streaming playback to WiFi only

Tags: ios, streaming, avfoundation, mp4, http-live-streaming

I'm developing a player using AVFoundation. The source videos I have no control over but they certainly violate:

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

REQUIREMENTS FOR APPS

...If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming. (Progressive download may be used for smaller clips.)...

I'm talking mp4 videos that are 100Mb+ for 3 to 5 min clips.

Again, 0 control over the source material but I have to play them.

Looking at AVFoundation, none of the classes I'm using, AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem, AVQueuePlayer and so on have a similar property to a NSURLSessionConfiguration's .allowsCellularAccess (at least that I can see)

So agreement with the client was to limit the streaming to Wifi only, but I see no way around at the moment to force streaming over WiFi only.

Any pointers on how to get around it?

Any help is MUCH appreciate

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this?